Merging multiple cell range with a single line of code
I'm doing some decluttering on a code I designed and wish to eliminate some lines that uses the same function each on a different range of cells, like the one below;
Cells(X, 11).Resize(, 2).Merge
Cells(X, 13).Resize(, 2).Merge
Cells(X, 15).Resize(, 2).Merge

I tried unifying this into a single line like below, but I coudn't make it work.
Range("Cells(X, 11).Resize(, 2), Cells(X, 13).Resize(, 2), Cells(X, 15).Resize(, 2)").Merge

Is there some other approach to this that I'm not seeing?

Don't understand what exactly you want. Your first the lines create 3 time 2 merged cells, while you last line create 1 time 6 merged cells - that a complete different thing

You've found the best possible. If X is a variable, you need to compose the address string like "K" & X & ":P" & X

Consider adding a sub that does the merging, with arguments being the base cell (or an array of cells) and an optional argument for the number of columns to merge (with the default being 2). Then you can just call that sub in your main code with something like: Merge Array(Cells(X, 11), Cells(X, 13), Cells(X, 15)) Probably more total lines (with the sub) but easier to follow and modify code.

For i = 1 To 3: Cells(X, 9).Offset(, i * 2).Resize(, 2).Merge: Next
